# Patterns to instantiate abstract class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract

I have an abtract class lets call it ClassAbstract.

I also have a number of concrete classes Class#NonAsbtract extends ClassAbstract.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
public void someMethod(some arguments) {
    // my solution : ClassAbstract ca = buildClassAbstract(enumArgument);
    ClassAbstract ca = new Class#NonAsbtract();
}
```

Right now I am using this method in the same class with someMethod:

```
private ClassAbstract buildClassAbstract(SomeEnum enum) {
    switch(enum) {
         case ARG_ONE:
              return new Class1NonAbstract();
    }
}
```

Do you think it's worth it to go to any pattern

Comment: Patterns solve problems in a specific context. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It depends on the problem that your code is solving.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do however, the Builder pattern springs to mind.  You can have a Builder which can create different implementations based on which one is appropriate.

Comment: I only need the abstract implementation of the concrete classes to use in the method and I can't change the arguments to get the Abstract from another place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Factory pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm).
You almost did it, just create factory class and move your `buildClassAbstract` method to it.

Comment: THank you I was thinking about that but I was wondering if there is another way to do that as this is the only place I need this (for the moment) and only 2 concrete implementations.

Comment: It is a standart way. Standarts are good. If you will name your class ClassAbstractFactory, everyone will know what doest it do, without even looking into the code.